# Excel VBA - 'IF' 'OR' formula causing Compile error: Syntax error

Tags: vba, if-statement, excel, excel-formula

I have written a simple 'IF' 'OR' formula in excel which checks if cells value is equal to a six character product code; the 'IF' test simple asks does cell A5 = "[product code]". If it does the formula returns 'Yes', if not 'No'.

I have tried to write a simple macro to input the formula for me. I seem to be getting an error which stats:

> **"Compile error: Syntax error"**

My formula shorted slightly is:

```
=IF(OR($A5="OIASLS",$A5="BMA003",$A5="CBRNSR",$A5="DTAPCO", [I have shorted the formula from here].................Yes","No").
```

My VBA code is:

```
Sub LevelTwoCourse()
'Formula to test if Product is a level 2 product. If Product code matches any code listed below formula returns "yes"
    Range("AF5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(OR(RC1=""OIASLS"",RC1=""BMA003"",RC1=""CBRNSR"",RC1=""DTAPCO"",RC1=""DTAPMC"",RC1=""DTAPMD"",RC1=""DTBFDR"",RC1=""DTBFFL"",RC1=""DTBLAS"",RC1=""DTDVFL"",RC1=""DTDVFR"",RC1=""DTDVVF"",RC1=""DTHLDR"",RC1=""DTHVCR"",RC1=""DTHVDR"",RC1=""DTHVHO"",RC1=""DTHVHR"",RC1=""DTLG3D"",RC1=""DTLG7D"",RC1=""DTLGAF"",RC1=""DTLGAS"",RC1=""DTLGEF"",RC1=""DTLGEX"",RC1=""DTLGFR"",R"& _
        "GHP"",RC1=""DTLGMC"",RC1=""DTMPOP"",RC1=""DTMPRF"",RC1=""DTOSMD"",RC1=""DTOTLD"",RC1=""DTRSDE"",RC1=""DTRSHP"",RC1=""DTRSRA"",RC1=""DTRSRC"",RC1=""DTRSRE"",RC1=""DTRSSP"",RC1=""DTRSSS"",RC1=""DTRSST"",RC1=""DTRSVH"",RC1=""DTRSYT"",RC1=""DTSCS1"",RC1=""DTTLMC"",RC1=""DTTLMD"",RC1=""FCFSHE"",RC1=""FCFSHS"",RC1=""FSCHVR"",RC1=""FSRU08"",RC1=""HRDRPM"",RC1=""IMASCM"",RC"& _
        "M"",RC1=""IMTHCM"",RC1=""IMTHWM"",RC1=""INPDMR"",RC1=""OBATTP"",RC1=""OIBACF"",RC1=""OIBAE2"",RC1=""OIBAEC"",RC1=""OIBAER"",RC1=""OIBAEY"",RC1=""OIBAM3"",RC1=""OIBAMT"",RC1=""OIBRFC"",RC1=""OIBRFR"",RC1=""OIFA4N"",RC1=""OIFBTF"",RC1=""OIHMSC"",RC1=""OIIE3D"",RC1=""OIIE5D"",RC1=""OIIEDA"",RC1=""OILOL2"",RC1=""OILOMA"",RC1=""OIRTOD"",RC1=""OISKFM"",RC1=""OISKFN"",RC1="& _
        "",RC1=""OISKIA"",RC1=""OISKIB"",RC1=""OISKPB"",RC1=""OISKPR"",RC1=""OISKSW"",RC1=""OISKTR"",RC1=""OISKWR"",RC1=""OISPLR"",RC1=""OISRTR"",RC1=""OIUKRO"",RC1=""OIWSBA"",RC1=""OIWSBB"",RC1=""OIWSBC"",RC1=""OIWSBD"",RC1=""OIWSBE"",RC1=""OIWSBF"",RC1=""OIWSBG"",RC1=""DTEXE1"",RC1=""FSRWMM"",RC1=""OIAPPP"",RC1=""OIAPPR"",RC1=""OIASLR"",RC1=""BMA001"",RC1=""BMA002"",RC1="""& _
        "RC1=""CBRNB2"",RC1=""CBRNBR"",RC1=""CBRNGI"",RC1=""CBRNGR"",RC1=""CBRNLO"",RC1=""CBRNSI"",RC1=""DTAPCR"",RC1=""DTAWDM"",RC1=""DTBFFR"",RC1=""DTBFIR"",RC1=""DTDVCB"",RC1=""DTDVCR"",RC1=""DTLGBR"",RC1=""DTOTHD"",RC1=""DTRSCE"",RC1=""DTRSCP"",RC1=""DTUSD1"",RC1=""FCFSDT"",RC1=""FCFSHR"",RC1=""FCSKRT"",RC1=""FSENG1"",RC1=""FSENG2"",RC1=""FSENG3"",RC1=""FSENG4"",RC1=""FS"& _
        "1=""FSRU02"",RC1=""FSRU03"",RC1=""FSRU04"",RC1=""FSRU05"",RC1=""FSRU06"",RC1=""FSRU07"",RC1=""FSRU09"",RC1=""FSRU10"",RC1=""FSRU11"",RC1=""FSRU12"",RC1=""FSRU15"",RC1=""FSRU16"",RC1=""FSRU17"",RC1=""FSRU18"",RC1=""FSRV01"",RC1=""FSRV02"",RC1=""FSRV03"",RC1=""FSRV04"",RC1=""FSRV05"",RC1=""FSRV06"",RC1=""FSRV07"",RC1=""FSRV08"",RC1=""FSRV09"",RC1=""FSRV10"",RC1=""FSRV"& _
        """FSRV12"",RC1=""FSRV15"",RC1=""FSRV16"",RC1=""FSRV17"",RC1=""FSRV18"",RC1=""HSSKPT"",RC1=""HSSLFT"",RC1=""INPLRF"",RC1=""OBATTW"",RC1=""OIBABI"",RC1=""OIBAR2"",RC1=""OIBASA"",RC1=""OIFA2N"",RC1=""OIFBCE"",RC1=""OIFBTE"",RC1=""OIFBTI"",RC1=""OIFHCO"",RC1=""OIFSUR"",RC1=""OIHCHM"",RC1=""OIHRPS"",RC1=""OIHSTD"",RC1=""OILOHC"",RC1=""OIRTIN"",RC1=""OISKEX"",RC1=""OISKHA"& _
        "OISKHF"",RC1=""OISKII"",RC1=""OISKMT"",RC1=""OISKSS"",RC1=""OISKUH"",RC1=""OISLEI"",RC1=""OIUKEC"",RC1=""OIUSCH"",RC1=""OIUSCR"",RC1=""OIUSLA""),""Yes"",""No"")"
End Sub
```

Any clues?

Comment: Taking a quick look at the OR statement,it looks as though your conditions are a little off at the continuation line breaks. For example, the first line of the OR ends with the letter "R" and the next begins with "GPH". I'm curious why you are not using a vlookup on a product list range, which would be a more natural way of doing this? That would also make it more maintainable if the product list changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Chuff! Instead of writing such a huge formula, why not keep that list in a separate column and then check if the relevant cell matches that value?

For example, let's say we maintain a list in `Col A` of `Sheet2` (See Screenshot below)

So a simple formula in say `B1` of `Sheet1` to check if `A1` has that word or not will exactly solve your problem. The other **benefit** is that you can **increase/reduce** your list in `Col A` of `Sheet2` **without** amending the formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1)>0,"Yes","No")
```

The VBA code for the above will be

```
Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,Sheet1!A1)>0,""Yes"",""No"")"
```

You may now amend the above formula/code to suit your needs :)

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: The cell which provided the answer to my “IF - OR” formula, a simple “yes” or 
“no” is part of a huge data list. A new data list is generated daily and saved as a .CSV file. Which is then tidied up using a VBA script I wrote? (part 1)

Comment: (part 2)The script adds some additional columns and formatting, and ideally I want it to write my formula to the first cell in one of the new columns. VLookup’s are good although they are reliant on the lookup list moving with the data and the user understand the VLookup function,

Comment: (part 3) for my purposes a VBA script which would format a file, create new columns and input any needed formula’s into the data is better in this instance. All my variables are written into the formula which can be simple copied and pasted into another sheets with a simple copy and past.